# How to pattern match on Map?

Tags: scala

```
val paths @ Array(key_dc_outputDirectory, key_dc_path) = Array("DC_BIN", "DC_PATH")
```

but below gives a compiler error:

```
val map @ Map(p1, p2) = Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2")
```

value Map is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member

What is the correct syntax to avoid the error?

Comment: Generally you can't perform this kind of operation on a Map because it provides no guarantee with respect to the ordering of elements.

Comment: @Chris : cte is Compile time error. i will make sure to use full form in future posts..

Answer (score 2):

The problem obviously is that `Map` does not have `unapplySeq` method. It might not have lots of sense to have it because you would not know in which order you would get your elements.

Anyhow, the closest I could get to is this:

```
scala> object MapOops {
     |   def apply[K,V](ps: (K,V)*): Map[K,V] =
     |     ps.toMap
     |
     |   def unapplySeq[K,V](m: Map[K,V]): Option[Seq[(K,V)]] =
     |     if(m.isEmpty) None else Some(m.toSeq)
     | }
defined object MapOops

scala> val map@MapOops(p1, p2) = MapOops(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
map: Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)
p1: (Int, String) = (1,one)
p2: (Int, String) = (2,two)
```

or, even shorter:

```
scala> val map@MapOops(p1, p2) = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)
p1: (Int, String) = (1,one)
p2: (Int, String) = (2,two)
```

It does not make sense to pimp `Map` with something like this:

`implicit class MapOops[K,V](val m: Map[K,V]) extends AnyVal`

Because when you use `Map` in pattern matching no implicit conversion could happen since `MapOops` type is not requested/implied.

For example: `case Map(...)` or `val Map(...)` would require type `Map`, not `MapOops` so implicit conversion will not take place and `unapplySeq` method will not be found. And if you use `MapOops` explicitly, then no implicit conversion is necessary.

If you use this pattern a lot then you might find this helper class useful, otherwise a more sensible solution is to have an extra conversion as in @jwvh's answer.